# Date formating issue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Hi I am having function for date formatting

```
def format_date date
    date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
end
```

My View code is like this

```
<input type="text" id="start" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" name='start_date' value="<%= params[:start_date] %>"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar">
```

I want to do this by `rails`. and If I do it by java-script it's still not working.

Comment: what is the error? Show your code written in `erb` tags

Comment: Hi Nithin. If i call it directly on arguments it didn't work well ... m iwrong with any syntax

Comment: from where have you called your `format_date` method

Comment: I waaana call it after params ... that didn't work ... can you suggest me where i m wrong

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, Here's an example how you can use

```
 <%= f.text_field 'start_date', id:"start", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Start Date", value:  params[:start_date].to_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
```

Comment: It gives me invalid date error.   <input type="text" id="start" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" name='start_date' value="<%= params[:start_date].to_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar">

Comment: can you inspect and show the result of `params[:start_date]`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.. to get the format as ddmmyy and limit selection of future dates

```
 var ToEndDate = new Date();
        $('#start').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                 weekStart: 1,
                 autoclose: true,
                 startDate: '01/01/1950',
                 endDate: ToEndDate, 
            });
```

**you can use it with form object such as:-**

```
 <%= f.text_field :date_of_birth ,:class=>"form-control input-lg "  ,:placeholder=>"Select Date of Birth",:id=>"start",:required=>true, :autofocus => true %>
```

where `date_of_birth` is field in `users` table(**for example**)

Comment: I am taking it from datepicker & then want format like ddmmyyy

Comment: @user2138918...i have updated my answer with the script for datepicker...use it and see.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to use this formatting to save it in db in this format and use it in the future? If I am right, you can do next:

In your **config/initializers** create file **time_formats.rb**.

Inside the file:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:mdy] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

Now you can simply format your date, for example before saving to db. In your model class:

```
# If your start_date attr is a string value in your db:
def format_date
  self.start_date.to_date.to_formatted_s(:mdy)
end

# If your start_date value is a date value in your db:
def format_date
  self.start_date.to_formatted_s(:mdy)
end

before_save :format_date
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi this is your method in which you are passing date and it convert to that format**

```
def format_date date
  date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
end
```

**By looking your view code I found that you are not calling the helper method, which you could call like bellow**

**My View code is like this**

```
<input type="text" id="start" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" name='start_date' value="<%= format_date params[:start_date] %>"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar">
```

**I have tested by passing Date.today object to the format_date method which is working fine if error is not resolving then check your params object.**

**If you are using date picker to change this then please follow bellow code**

**View**

```
<input type="text" id="start" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" name='start_date' value="<%= params[:start_date],data: { 'date-format' =>"DD/MM/YYYY", 'behaviour' => 'no-past-datepicker', 'rule-dateFormat' => true } %>"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar">
```

This you have to put in your js file also need to require it in application.js by just putting

**//= require jquery.ui.datepicker**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function () {
    $("#start").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Iam getting error on this as undefined method `strftime' for "07/30/2014":String

Comment: Actually your format is wrong, but still you want to run this it will work just add this to your params , "07/30/2014".split('/').join('-')
and call that method as it is mention

Comment: Actually format of date will be like 07-30-2014 it will work so you need to call like format_date(params[:start_date]..split('/').join('-'))